# find string in word and format para

Tags: excel, vba

how to find Start with "一、" "二、" "三、"（chinese 1、2、3） ... in word, than change the paragraph font to bold with Regular expression

```
For Each pa In .Paragraphs
            If pa.Range.Find.execute("一、") Then
            pa.Range.Font.Name = "黑体"
            End If
            Next pa
```

display "Object does not support the property or method" on

```
If pa.Range.Find.excute("一、") Then
```

Comment: Typo! The method is Find.ex**e**cute (you missed an `e`).

Comment: OK，it's work,but Regular expression

Comment: Have a look at [how to implement RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) . It is for Excel but works almost the same in Word.